# Define Global variable In SilverLight with Prism Pattern?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, prism

HI
Let me explain about my problem:

I have a Silver-Light application developed base on Prism. In This app we need to use User/Password (Authenticate Our user`s) for separating permission levels. So for Doing this We wrote method in Service App (WCF web service) for detecting user and if User is valid-one, user can use App. After that(Detecting method) as Result method return valid user.

For using this User-Information we need define Global User-variable, and any Modules can access to this variable. But there is another big problem. We must define User-variable Per Session (any User work with his\her user-variable). Also in any calls from modules the new session will be create.

#### So how define global variable with these terms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in a static variable on the client side.  After passing it pack set it to a static variable in a class, lets say User, and then from anywhere you can `User.CurrentUser` and have access to that object.  You shouldn't have any session issues as long as you do everything on the client side.